# How to know for for sure that the TargetProperty is the DataContext Property within a Markup Extension

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, datacontext, markup-extensions

I am working on a markup extension that is only supposed to work when assigned to a DataContext Dependency Property.

This is enforced by the extension in the following manner:

```
public abstract class DataContextAssignableExtensionBase  : MarkupExtension
 {

    private void ThrowOnUnsupportedProperty(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var dataContextProp = TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;

        if (dataContextProp == null)
            throw new ...
        if (!(dataContextProp.Name.Equals("DataContext") || dataContextProp.Name.Equals("RuntimeDataContext")))
            throw new ...
    }
}
```

Now, DataContext will most probably forever remain named DataContext, but still..

I would like a more "safe" way to make sure that the extension is assigned to the DataContext Dependency Property.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just do a reference comparison against the property definition:

```
if (dataContextProp != FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty)
    throw ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @MikeStrobel said, the only way to know whether or not a given DependencyProperty is the DataContext property at both design and runtime, in .NET 4.5 and VS2013 is:

```
if(( dependencyProperty == FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty
 ||  dependencyProperty == FrameworkContentElement.DataContextProperty)
|| (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(dependencyObject)&&
 dataContextProp.Name.Equals("RuntimeDataContext") )))
{

}
```

Where dependencyProperty and dependencyObject are references obtained somehow,

And dependencyProperty was obtained in context to the dependencyObject reference.